# I teleported too far away and now the game crashes on world load

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues

I'm stuck in Minecraft! I was flying around teleporting myself to random locations to find new biomes to build on. I teleported to 12345678,64,12345678 and it froze. I restarted minecraft and my computer like 20 times and every time I loaded that world, it froze. I started a new world and it worked fine so I know it's not Minecraft. I think it is the place I am and I don't know how to get out. I don't want to start a new world as I have found rare biomes that took me forever to find. Is there a way to change your location outside of Minecraft like in the save file?

Comment: ...'rare biomes'?

Comment: True that, Gnome!

Answer (score 11):

If you go to your minecraft saves folder (usually something like C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Roaming.minecraft\saves) there will be a folder called **players**.

Go into that folder and delete the file with your name on it, and the next time you enter the world it should spawn you close to 0,64,0 rather than the extreme location you teleported to. Note that you will lose any items and experience you currently carry.

An alternative solution is to use a third party program like MCedit to edit your .dat file and change the location in the file. I'm afraid I don't know much about those though.

Comment: i already did the delete and it just created a new file with me at the same coords. ill try the MCedit though where do i get it?

Comment: http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/13807-mcedit-minecraft-world-editor-now-open-source/ should be the official forum thread.

Comment: it worked! after i figured out how to move my player, i spawned out of the corrupt chunk! thank you!

Comment: @cobra0798 Happy to be of help :)

Comment: @cobra0798 if this answer solved your problem, accept it.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to deleting your level.dat, as Hex described, there are other, less destructive options available if you care about your inventory:

- As mentioned, [MCEdit](https://github.com/mcedit/mcedit/downloads) is a great way to easily move your current location. As an added bonus, it can edit inventories, spawn locations, terrain, and a variety of other things, so it's certainly a helpful item to have in your Minecraft toolbox.
- If you are willing to enter coordinates, you can change the x, y, and z positions of the player using an NBT editor like [NBTExplorer](http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/840677-nbtexplorer/) or [NEINEdit](http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/63854-neinedit-nbt-editor-for-mac-os-x/). Just keep in mind that the y coordinate is vertical, not z.

Answer (score 1):

I teleported myself millions of blocks in the air on a 1.13.2 LAN world and all I had to do was have the host get a repeating command block teleporting me low to the ground, and i joined back twice and it was fine.