# Why am I stuck underground?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [I teleported too far away and now the game crashes on world load](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/80322/i-teleported-too-far-away-and-now-the-game-crashes-on-world-load)

I just jumped off a really tall tower and died. When I respawned I respawned underground. For some reason my character is shaking and I can't move, I can only look around but not move. For some reason have 64 cobblestone after respawning, straight away. Can anyone tell me how to get out or kill myself? I don't want to quit because I made an amazing castle with lots of stuff in it!

Comment: First thing to try in your situation is probably to press T (chat) and type /kill. If that fails, check the question that Ender linked.

Answer (score 1):

Try closing minecraft, and if you are still stuck like that, close and open again. The same thing happens to me when I'm jumping a lot, ie. single block stairs.
If you want to kill yourself, then make sure minecraft is updated to 1.3.1, then type in "/kill" and press enter. This will only work if you have enabled cheats, but that was not specified.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Do cheats need to be enabled in order to /kill yourself?