# Minecraft LAN world fails to load Player 2 without freezing him

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, mcedit

I was in a 1.13.2 LAN world with my friend, and while joking around, I teleported him to something on the order of [~, 2e24, ~] and It froze him and kicked him from the world. He kept trying to rejoin but it didn't work. I tried using command blocks to change his spawn, but nothing worked.

I've seen posts on here that explain how to fix this issue: ([I teleported too far away and now the game crashes on world load](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/80322/i-teleported-too-far-away-and-now-the-game-crashes-on-world-load))
But the solution involved MCedit, which wasn't working for me (I presume because of MC being in 1.13.2)

The other posts' solution mentioned going into the saves folder and deleting player data, but In my saves folder, the player data is unassigned to each player, ad I don't want to accidentally delete the wrong one, making the world un-joinable for all players.I do think /tp is slightly OP, and I also think it should have limits based on proximity.
Any consideration would be much appreciated!

Comment: You can look at the "date modified" for the player data. Player 2 logs out, wait 5 minutes, and then you should be able to identify which file belongs to which player.

Comment: This is weird. Teleporting to 2e24 should just fail with an error message. Or teleport you to 3e7, the maximum.

Answer (score 0):

You can download [Mcedit](http://www.mcedit.net/) and move the player with the tool, this tool can be usefull for creating world or moving entity like player.

don't tp you friend to far, there is a limit in the minecraft world, behond this "wall" his game may do wierd stuff like crash or being unable to play.

there is a trick if you want, prepare the tp commande and as soon he connect tp him. If it don't work try with Mcedit.